# how to compute Big O complexity in this recursive algorithms?

Tags: recursion, big-o, complexity-theory

The following recursive code is used to compute how many different possible ways that could sum a given number.

Input:4

Output: 
1111
112
121
112
22
13
31
4
There are 8 (2^(n-1)) different ways to get 4.

I wanna know what's the Big O complexity of this algorithm? I appreciate a basic thinking process of dealing with recursive algorithms. Another questions, why the the number of ways is 2^(n-1)? I can't figure that out from the algorithm. Thank you guys very much!

```
    public static int recursive(int n, String out){

    int count=0;

    if (n==0) {
        System.out.println(out);
        return 1;
    } else if (n>0) {

        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            count+=recursive(n-i, out+" "+Integer.toString(i));
        }

        return count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BigO (order of) complexity can be a somewhat loose term.  It's used for thumbnail estimates of algorithm performance.

If you look at the code you have given you can start my imagining that the code is not recursive.  In that case the algo is on the order of n (the main for loop).  The recursive function is called n times each invoking (n-1)! (n-1 factorial) times (n-1 .. 0).  So it looks to me like what you have is

O(n(n-1)!) => O(n!)

This is a thumbnail of how many string append operations occur (the contents of the main for loop, which is the main thing the code is doing).